# How to scan files during uploads with the use of FileUpload asp.net server control

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, security, mcafee

In continuation to my previous research at this link : [Security Risks or concerns with the use of FileUpload control of asp.net - and suggested solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966893/security-risks-or-concerns-with-the-use-of-fileupload-control-of-asp-net-and-su)

I need to know how to Scan files during upload, also how to intimate user if file is virus affected and abort the operation.

Any answer for this highly appreciable.

Thanks in advance!

Edited - In addition to above, we have McAfee Antivirus installed on our servers. I heard that there is some APIS for this work for Symantac Antivirus but I am not sure about McAfee antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know how to Scan files during upload, also how to intimate user if file is virus affected and abort the operation.

You mean a virus scan while a file is being uploaded from the client? This is hardly possible using standard tools.

Scan the file *after* it has been uploaded; delete the file and show the user a reject message if anything malicious was found.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. i edited my original question. Actually this kind of operation is possible as I googled and found that there are some APIS for Symantac Antivirus but I need to know about McAfee.

Comment: @Rick then your best bet may be asking McAfee themselves.