# How to filter C# File upload's Content type to all kind of text files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am looking for a solution of how to filter all kind of text files from upload control.
For example, file extension can be text.fa,text.fasta or text.fastq. These are DNA sequence file formats.

I am trying to read the text file uploaded and save the content to database. Validation is done on server side.The problem is the following validation is that only .text extension files are valid. This is the type of file I also want to be included in valid list: http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/fasta

C#

```
//what should I change instead of this. It only works for .txt extension files.
FileUpload.PostedFile.ContentType == "text/plain"
```

Comment: There is a workaround in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780191/how-to-restrict-file-type-in-fileupload-control

Comment: What exact behavior are you trying to obtain? Are you trying to show the files that appear in selection dialog somewhere? Are you trying to validate that the selected file is the correct type? Is that validation being done on the client or the server? Your question is missing a lot of important information. Edit it and add more detail.

Comment: @JimMischel I put some more information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with. Not the best one but it works.

```
string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload.FileName);//get file extension                
string[] extList = { ".txt", ".fasta", ".fa", ".fna", ".ffn", ".faa", ".frn", ".fas" };// allowed extension list
int extPos = Array.IndexOf(extList, extension);  
if(exPos > -1){

}
else{
}
```