# ASP.NET VB , how to restrict filetype to upload?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

I have a sub to upload file. How do I restrict the filetype that can be uploaded? I don't want the user to be able to upload `.exe`, `.dll`, `.ini` files. Right now any files can be uploaded.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
        Try
            FileUpload1.SaveAs("C:\Uploads\" & _
                FileUpload1.FileName)
            Label1.Text = "File name: " & _
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName & "<br>" & _
                "File Size: " & _
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength & "<br>" & _
                "Content type: " & _
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType & "<br>" & _
                "Location Saved: C:\Uploads\" & _
                FileUpload1.FileName
        Catch ex As Exception
            Label1.Text = "ERROR: " & ex.Message.ToString()
        End Try
    Else
        Label1.Text = "You have not specified a file."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: possibly duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780191/how-to-restrict-file-type-in-fileupload-control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
      Try
        if FileUpload1.FileName.ToLower().Contains(".exe") or FileUpload1.FileName.ToLower().Contains(".dll")  or FileUpload1.FileName.ToLower().Contains(".ini") 
        ' show your alert here stating this type of files are not allowed
        return
        End if
        FileUpload1.SaveAs("C:\Uploads\" & _
            FileUpload1.FileName)
        Label1.Text = "File name: " & _
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName & "<br>" & _
            "File Size: " & _
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength & "<br>" & _
            "Content type: " & _
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType & "<br>" & _
            "Location Saved: C:\Uploads\" & _
            FileUpload1.FileName
      Catch ex As Exception
            Label1.Text = "ERROR: " & ex.Message.ToString()
      End Try
      Else
            Label1.Text = "You have not specified a file."
      End If
```

[But, I would suggest you client side check will be better too.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4237161/2630817)

Comment: Welcome, don't forget to vote up and accept the answer. :)

Comment: If someone change the file extension from exe to txt it will upload. What will be the solution here.